# manually replacing NA with POSIX datetime values time series r

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, posixct

I have a time series with hourly data like this:

```
    Date               x
...
54 2004-03-24 01:00:00 37
55 2004-03-24 02:00:00 63
56 2004-03-24 03:00:00 64
57 2004-03-24 04:00:00 56
58 2004-03-24 05:00:00 30
59 NA                  46
60 2004-03-24 07:00:00 53
61 2004-03-24 08:00:00 27
...
```

It is stored in a a data.frame object `df`.

Since there are only a few NA values and it's obvious what the missing values are I have tried replacing them manually. I did it using

`df$Date[59] <- "2004-03-28 06:00:00"` but it didn't quite work. What I got was that the y-m-d part got changed correctly but the hour got set to 00:00:00.

So in the console it gave this:

```
> df$Date[59] <- "2004-03-24 06:00:00"
> df$Date[59]
[1] "2004-03-24 CET"
```

And in the `View(df)` the row got changed from `59 NA` to `59 2004-03-24 00:00:00 46`

What am I doing wrong?

The dates are of the following type:

```
> class(df$Date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: Can you try `df$Date[59] <- as.POSIXct("2004-03-24 06:00:00")`?

Comment: Yes it has the same effect